# Find $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{1}(f(x+t)-f(x))xdx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function with $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=0$, find 
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{1}x(f(x+t)-f(x))\, dx$$

Comment: the limit just gives you an $f'(x)$

Comment: @tired $f$ is not necessarily differentiable.

Comment: @MarkViola oh, correct. didn't thought about that

Comment: If $x > 1-t$, then $f(x+t)$ isn't defined. The domain of $f$ should be larger, e.g. $[0,2]$. Hint: Much of the integral cancels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By variable changing $x=u-t$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1xf(x+t)dx
&=\int_t^{1+t}(u-t)f(u)du\\
&=\int_t^{1+t}uf(u)du-t\int_t^{1+t}f(u)du\\
\end{align*}
hence
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{1}x(f(x+t)-f(x))\, dx
&=\lim_{t\to 0}\left[\frac 1t\left(\int_t^{1+t}uf(u)-\int_0^1xf(x)dx\right)-\int_t^{1+t}f(u)du\right]\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0}\left[\frac 1t\left(\int_1^{1+t}uf(u)-\int_0^txf(x)dx\right)-\int_t^{1+t}f(u)du\right]\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\int_1^{1+t}uf(u)}t-\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\int_0^txf(x)dx}t-\int_0^1f(u)du\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0}(1+t)f(1+t)-\lim_{t\to 0}tf(t)\\
&=f(1)
\end{align*}
where I use L'Hopital rule.